# Failed to load in Storage Browser

Tags: browser, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded some files into Google Cloud Storage. Now, I would like to view the data in the Google Developer Console under `Storage->Cloud Storage->Storage Browser` by clicking on the created subfolder. Although having the status `Is owner` in `Project_Name->Permissions` I get the error message `Failed to load` (see attched picture). A collague of mine - having also the permission `Is owner` - has full access via the browser interface.

So, what do I have to additionally change in order to gain access via the web interface?

[image]

Comment: If you're uing Chrome browser, try incongnito window or try a different web browser. Also, what kind of file is it? will it happens the same if you try with a simple text file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome. Interesting, with Opera it works perfectly fine. Strange... how is that? The only thing that comes into my mind right now could be that it is due to two gmail accounts I'm using with Chrome. The first is my private one and the second is the gmail account for accessing compute engine etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen issue like this when having multiple users in a single Chrome Browser. You can [manage multiple users on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en) to avoid possible conflicts, visit the link provided to guide you on how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Open an incognito window in Chrome and see if the problem persists. If so, like in my case, you can resolve by only having one user logged in to Chrome.